# Is there any relationship between the recent LHCb results on lepton universality violation and Bells Ineqalities?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, standard-model, large-hadron-collider, bells-inequality

[Link to article re LHCb results](https://home.cern/news/news/physics/intriguing-new-result-lhcb-experiment-cern)

As a layperson, my knowledge is limited to what i can understand from pop sci books. Having recently read about (although not quite understood!) Bells Theorem, it seemed a similar concept was being demonstrated at LHCb in that the 1:1 expected ratio was violated. Is Bells Theorem relevant here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no connection.

The Bell inequalities violation means that the quantum theory works and the local hidden variables idea fails.

The lepton universality is the property of the Standard Model which is a quantum theory. However you may easily consider another quantum theory where there is no lepton universality. It would not change the fact that the basic principles of the quantum theory work.